# Select the first range of contiguous data in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to, in each worksheet, select and copy only the first range of the contiguous data in column B (e.g. B3:B5 with values 3, 5, 2 in the table below) before any blanks.
The length of the values vary across worksheets, but the data I want always start from cell "B3".
I don't want any values under Heading5 or in other columns. In some worksheets, there is no Heading5 and values beneath it.
I read some posts about Intersect and ActiveCell properties, but I don't know how to apply them.. New to VBA - thank you for your help!

```
A        B        C
Heading1 Heading2 Heading3
2        3        6
3        5        8
4        2        4

Heading4 Heading5 Heading6
24       67       2
25       34       5
4        6        12
```

Comment: You have been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: `Range("B3",Range("B3").End(xlDown))` will return go down to the first blank cell.  like hitting ctrl-downarrow.

Comment: Thank  you very much Scott @Scott Craner! I tried: Set rng = Range("B3", Range("B3).End(xlDown)), and then: rng.Select. But when I run the VBA, it highlights rng.Select and says error...May I know what's wrong?

Comment: I am sorry findwindow @findwindow - but I could not find any solutions for this and all other codes I wrote were unrelated... I normally show efforts but I will definitely try harder next time.

Comment: Range(Range("B3"),Range("B3").End(xlDown)) maybe? (Didn't try, should work though.) Just record a freaking ctrl-shift-down, man! :)

Comment: @Grinsummer When you write `Set rng = Range("B3", Range("B3).End(xlDown))` do you qualify it to a *specific* worksheet, since you wrote *in each worksheet*. This is important as you may get unexpected results if the active sheet is not the one you suppose it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you idea, try :

```
Columns("B").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "B")).Select
```

This will select the first blank cell in column B.
Now if you want this cell reference, simply use :

```
MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
```

And this will give you **`$B$6`** (Assuming your data start from A1).

***NOTE**: You need to twik it use it with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Found out a solution for this, which works for me:

```
Dim last As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim I as integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 8 to WS_Count

last = Worksheets(I).Cells(3, "B").End(xlDown).Row
Set rng = Worksheets(I).Range("B3:B" & last)

Next I
```